# How to generate click event after page refresh?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I am using JQuery `tabs()` . I am using cookies to save selected tab.
Here, the purpose is to maintain that selected tab in active state(and all other tabs in disable state) even after page refresh.

The tab value is persists in cookie but the data corresponding to that tab will be appended only after click event fires. So,I want to generate click event after page is being refreshed.

```
                var category = $.cookie("category");//consists selected tab

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var url = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
                var paramValues;
                var params = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
                    paramValues = url[i].split("=");
                    params.push(paramValues);
                }
                id = params[0][0];
                type = params[1][1];
                subtype = params[2][1];
                getListOfDocs(id, category, type, subtype);//get the data from db append it to the html element
                $("#tabs").tabs();  
                $(".dtls").click(function(e) {
                    category = $(this).html();
                    $.cookie("category", category);
                    getListOfDocs(id, category, type, subtype);
                    $("li[class*='category']").removeClass("ui-state-active");
                    $("li[class*='category']").removeClass("ui-tabs-active");
                    $("li[class='categorynws']").removeClass("ui-state-default");//categorynws isclass of first tab
                    $(".category" + $.cookie('category')).addClass("ui-state-active");
                });
            }

            function getListOfDocs(id, category, type, subtype) {
                //ajax call
                success : function(data){//inside success parameter of ajax
                    $("#" + category).html(data[0]);//                  
                    console.log($("#" + category).html());//it results required data,but not displayed in browser

                }
            }

            <html>
                <body>
                                    <div id="tabs">
                                <ul id="ulid" class="tabs">
                                    <li class="categorynws">
                                        <a href="#nwsTab" title="nws Details" id="nwsdtls" class="dtls">nws</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="categoryann">
                                        <a href="#annTab" title="ann Details" id="anndtls" class="dtls">ann</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="categoryvdo">
                                        <a href="#vdosTab" id="vdodtls" class="dtls">vdo</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="categoryimgs">
                                        <a href="#imgsTab" title="imgsList" id="imgsdtls" class="dtls" >imgs</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="categoryMoviemkng">
                                        <a href="#mkngTab" title="mkng Of this Movie" id="moviemkngdtls" class="dtls">Moviemkng</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="categorytinfo">
                                        <a href="#tinfoTab" title="Trade Information of a Movie" id="tinfodtls"  class="dtls">tinfo</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!--Add button-->
                                <a href="mvs.html?mvs" role="button" class="btn  pull-right" title="It will navigate you to the mvs list" id="mvsList">mvs</a>
                                <a href="#" role="button" class="btn  pull-right" title="You can add here" id="addMore">Add</a>

                                <div id="nwsTab" class="tabs">
                                    <div id="nws"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="annTab" class="tabs">
                                    <div id="ann"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="tvdoTab" class="tabs">
                                    <div id="tvdo"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="vdosTab" class="tabs">
                                    <div id="vdo"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="imgsTab" class="tabs">
                                    <div id="imgs"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="mkngTab" class="tabs">
                                    <div id="Mvemkng"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="tinfoTab" class="tabs">
                                    <div id="tinfo"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: It would be easy for answer if you post your `code`

Comment: @Satinder singh : I posted my code

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option to set the default tab

```
$('#mytab').tabs({
    active: parseInt($.cookie('myactivetab'), 10) || 0
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zsb8D/)

*Note: Hoping you are using a [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)*

Comment: here 10 and 1 represents expirydate specification?@Arun

Comment: @no, it is  the radix parameter to the [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method

Comment: No,it's not working.How can i detect page refresh?I used '(window).unload(function(){alert("unload fired"})' in **$(document).ready()**   to detect page refresh..when this "unload" will be fired.How do i detect page refresh..@Arun

Comment: @Divya: are you doing some serverside logic over your tab ?

Comment: iam able to get the tab value.but the code is not displayed in the browser.
observe the code in success parameter of ajax.@ Arun

Comment: you need to change `$("#tabs").tabs();` to `    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        active: parseInt($.cookie('myactivetab'), 10) || 0,
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            $.cookie('myactivetab', ui.newTab.index())
        }
    });`

Comment: '$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      active: parseInt($.cookie('myactivetab'), 10) || 0,
      activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $.cookie('myactivetab', ui.tabs.index()) 
       } 
      });' I applied as it apeared on the screen.' alert("ActiveTab : ");
      alert($.cookie("myactivetab"));'  results in "null" @Arun P Johny